# A p2p secure chat application need more ressources to establish the work

Tags: python, django, security, p2p, hashgraph

I want to do this so called p2p chat app project, and I need some clear guidance and ressources where I can find some good p2p documentation or courses so I can digest this notion, I'm not so familiar woth it even though I have some basic knowledge about it

I hope u suggest some great ressources where I can find a p2p based book or documentation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.